# Google apps script UrlFetchApp and nodejs axios return different result; MyFitnessPal diary

Tags: node.js, http, google-apps-script, axios, http-post

I'm trying to fetch my diary from MyFitnessPal and natively I wrote the following code that works:

```
"use strict";
const axios = require('axios')

async function getReport(username) {
  const foodLog = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://www.myfitnesspal.com/api/services/authenticate_diary_key/${username}`,
    data: {
      from: "2023-01-20",
      to: "2023-01-30",
      show_food_diary: 1,
      show_exercise_diary: 1,
      show_food_notes: 0,
      show_exercise_notes: 0,
      key: ""
    }
  })

  // do stuff with foodLog
}
```

The response contains an array of dates and each date containing meals and etc.

However when I make the exact same request to MyFitnessPal, but inside the google apps script using UrlFetchApp, I get an empty response:

```
function getReport(username) {
  const url = `https://www.myfitnesspal.com/api/services/authenticate_diary_key/${username}`
  const payload = {
      from: "2023-01-20",
      to: "2023-01-30",
      show_food_diary: 1,
      show_exercise_diary: 1,
      show_food_notes: 0,
      show_exercise_notes: 0,
      key: ""
    }
  
  const options = {
    payload,
    method: 'post'
  }

  try {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
    console.log(response.getResponseCode()) //200
    console.log(response.getContentText()) // []
  } catch (error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

The request passes without an error with status 200, but I get an emty array as a response. Am I missing something?

You can easily replicate the bug, by passing your MyFitnessPal username to getReport(), but make sure diary sharing is set to "Public" and you have logged meals for the dates you select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert your node.js script to Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your showing node.js script, it seems that the request body is sent as JSON with `Content-Type` of `application/json`. On the other hand, when I saw your showing Google Apps Script, it seemed that the request body is sent as the form data. This might be the reason for your current issue.

When these points are reflected in your showing Google Apps Script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const options = {
  payload,
  method: 'post'
}
```

#### To:

```
const options = {
  payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
  method: 'post',
  contentType: "application/json"
}
```

#### Note:

- If an error occurs, please include `Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"` in the request header and test it again.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Hi, I had tried setting the content type to application/json, but got 500. The mistake was not stringifying the payload. Thank you!